# How to return the data of an iterate function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, return, loops

i wrote some code in codeigniter

index controller using model '**navigation**':

```
$this->load->model('navigation');
$data['template']=$this->navigation->nav_template();
```

the nav_template() function generate string that will be output in brower:

```
    function nav_template($uplevel=0)
    {
        $tablename=$this->db->dbprefix("test");
        $sql="select * from $tablename where id_parent=$uplevel "
        $menu_item=$this->db->query($sql);

        foreach($menu_item->result_array() as $row)
        {
            if($something)
            {
                if
                {
                    echo 'some str';
                }
                self::nav_template($uplevel);//call self
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'other str';
            }
        }
        echo '</ul>';

    }
```

in view file i am using an `<?php echo $template ?>`
but as we all known , i am using echo() to output string. i wanted to store the string in some php varialbe that can be used in view file template tag.

and the nav_template() function just called itself using **self** php keyword.
nowhere to define the var like this:
`$template='';` and no where to return the string?
so , can anyone tell me how to return the output string within the **nav_template()** instead of echo it directly to browser?

ps: the output data is the formatted html code that will generate a treeview with help of some javascript scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function nav_template($uplevel=0)
{
    $tablename=$this->db->dbprefix("test");
    $sql="select * from $tablename where id_parent=$uplevel "
    $menu_item=$this->db->query($sql);
    $out = "";
    foreach($menu_item->result_array() as $row)
    {
        if($something)
        {

            $out .= self::nav_template($uplevel);
        }
        else
        {
            $out .= 'other str';
        }
    }
    $out.= '</ul>';
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: `$out .= self::nav_template($uplevel);` i never thought of this. solved! thx! 谢谢！